# how to render html page after ajax success from django backend

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x

I want to render html page after ajax success. but i am not getting the proper path for the file. I am using django backend. I am not using django inbuilt function to authenticate. [this is my python code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmIlM.png)
[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmb51.png)
[this is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2t9Z.png)

```js
//this is my javascript code

function admin_login(){
    username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    console.log(username+password);
    data={
                    "username":username,
                    "password":password
                }
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin_login/",
                data:JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function(data) {
                  console.log('sucessfully loggedin')
                  window.location.href = "/chat/templates/user.html";
                }
            });

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to redirect to a template. Django doesn't work like that.

With or without a redirect, a request from the browser always needs to go to a URL that is handled by a view. Your redirect should be to an actual URL listed in your urls.py.

Alternatively, given that this is a completely standard form that has no need for Ajax, you could remove the script completely. Just let the form submit in the normal way and redirect as the Django code determines.